# Is there a way for various online photo services to import the same keywords/tags added in Lighroom?

Tags: lightroom, web, tagging, keywords

Flickr seems to import the keywords (tags) correctly.  Why won't these automatically import into other online sites when I add a photo? (namely 500px, Fine Art America)

I manage my tags in a document that consist of the photo title and the associated tags (then copy and paste) but I would like to streamline this process which is becoming a bit of a chore. 
How can I ensure that keywords added in LR are honored as tags when I upload a photo to the above-mentioned online services?

EDIT:
I should mention that in my workflow I do not use plugins to upload publish photos to the online photo sites. I export all photos to a folder structure on my  hard drive and then upload those exported jpegs manually.

Answer (score 3):

Lightroom is great about using the fairly standard EXIF and ITPC meta fields for things. Keywords, for example, are stored in the keywords field. Since those are standard fields, other programs and websites can read that meta, also. It's actually pretty simple to do in most languages; I've written some Perl stuff with Exiftool to read/write this meta.

Simply and sadly, if you find it works on Flickr but not other sites, chances are those other sites haven't implemented that capability.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you upload to the photo service and/or how the photo service's API is implemented in Lightroom 4 (if you use LR4).  I know that if you use LR4's syncing platform that it'll upload keywords etc of the photos to SmugMug.com (just tried it) and keep those keywords in sync if you change them.  I haven't tried Flickr's syncing but I'd assume it works the same.